# How do I handle long text labels on a universal storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uilabel

If the text of a label in a universal storyboard is too long to fit **some** resolutions, how do I accommodate it?

**Storyboard View**

[image: Storyboard View]

**iPhone 6 Emulator**

[image: iPhone 6 Emulator]

I'm not sure if there is a *proper* way to go about this according to the guidelines, but I would assume I would either text wrap onto multiple lines or adjust the font size automatically.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a simple gif, which can help you to understand it better.

[image]

Comment: What does Update Frames do?

Really neat, thanks a lot!

Comment: It just resolves the invalid frame sizes after you have set proper constraints to ui elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can do either. First set the constraints so that the UILabel does not go past the edge of the screen. Then you have two options. Either set the minimum font size of set the number of lines to 0 (or both).

All of these settings can be set in storyboard.

**Edit to following your comment**

Constraints are usually set in the storyboard and dictate how a view is drawn based on the device you are using. It's a large and critical subject and [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) has a very good two part tutorial on it.

Comment: I've already set the lines to 0, but I can't seem to set any constraints. "The selected views have no constraints. At build time, explicit left, top, width, and height constraints will be generated for the view."